# WLClient addGlobalHeader does not work

Tags: objective-c, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-studio

I am trying to set global headers to send specific security information to the backend adapter. This does not seem to work for native iOS application using  Objective-C. I am sure, I am missing something.

Here is my simple example:

```
NSLog(@"Invoking Procedure...");
WLProcedureInvocationData *myInvocationData = [[WLProcedureInvocationData alloc] initWithAdapterName:@"RSSReader" procedureName:@"getStories"];
MyInvokeListener *invokeListener = [[MyInvokeListener alloc] initWithController: self];
[[WLClient sharedInstance] addGlobalHeader:@"header1" headerValue:@"header1"];
[[WLClient sharedInstance] invokeProcedure:myInvocationData withDelegate:invokeListener];
```

The header sent do not change at all.

Comment: Are you trying to change the Cookie header with this, or just any random header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you checking if the headers were sent?
Which exact version of MobileFirst?

Steps I've done to reproduce:

- Running MobileFirst Studio 6.3.0.00.20150130-1638
- I've downloaded the invoke in ios sample (https://ibm.biz/BdEw79)
- Added your `addGlobalHeader` line in my `doInvokeProcedure`:

  ```
  - (IBAction)doInvokeProcedure:(UIButton *)sender {
  [self updateView:@"Invoking Procedure..."];
  NSLog(@"Invoking Procedure...");
  WLProcedureInvocationData *myInvocationData = [[WLProcedureInvocationData alloc] initWithAdapterName:@"RSSReader" procedureName:@"getStories"];
  MyInvokeListener *invokeListener = [[MyInvokeListener alloc] initWithController: self];
  [[WLClient sharedInstance] addGlobalHeader:@"header1" headerValue:@"header1"];
  [[WLClient sharedInstance] invokeProcedure:myInvocationData withDelegate:invokeListener];

  }
  ```
- Captured the traffic in WireShark:

  ```
  POST /InvokingAdapterProceduresNative/apps/services/api/InvokingAdapterProceduresiOS/iOSnative/query HTTP/1.1
  Host: localhost:10080
  X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
  User-Agent: InvokingAdapterProceduresiOS/1.0 (iPhone Simulator; iOS 8.1; Scale/2.00)/WLNativeAPI/6.3.0.00.20150130-1638
  Cookie: WL_PERSISTENT_COOKIE=279ea643-f731-4c5e-8a59-74ed4842b3d8; JSESSIONID=0000x8PNWpTDWKW73FnPaw9oTAm:42599173-098f-4ab1-b562-68c6a8e1f345
  WL-Instance-Id: 7kreem49ql20l2pdf1fuq9q0kc
  x-wl-clientlog-osversion: 8.1
  x-wl-clientlog-env: iOSnative
  header1: header1
  x-wl-clientlog-deviceId: 18A44BA7-4DF9-411B-9577-5954C8E44921
  x-wl-clientlog-model: x86_64
  x-wl-analytics-tracking-id: 6D6B72FD-820C-4EF8-AE45-205723E464FF
  Content-Length: 112
  Connection: keep-alive
  x-wl-clientlog-appname: InvokingAdapterProceduresiOS
  x-wl-platform-version: 6.3.0.00.20150130-1638
  Accept-Language: en
  x-wl-clientlog-appversion: 1.0
  Accept: */*
  Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8
  Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
  x-wl-app-version: 1.0
  ```

Notice the `header1: header1` in the middle.

Comment: Nathan, I used exactly the same example, running it again and I can see the headers in WireShark too. Strange enough, the headers are not listed in the output as you can see here:

Comment: {
 "Accept-Language" = en;
 "User-Agent" = "InvokingAdapterProceduresiOS/1.0 (iPhone Simulator; iOS 8.1; Scale/2.00)/WLNativeAPI/6.3.0.00.20141121-0732";
 "X-Requested-With" = XMLHttpRequest;
 "x-wl-app-version" = "1.0";
 "x-wl-clientlog-appname" = InvokingAdapterProceduresiOS;
 "x-wl-clientlog-appversion" = "1.0";
 "x-wl-clientlog-deviceId" = "310E52D3-9D07-4EFD-B19B-1FBA9EC70503";
 "x-wl-clientlog-env" = iOSnative;
 "x-wl-clientlog-model" = "x86_64";
 "x-wl-clientlog-osversion" = "8.1";
 "x-wl-platform-version" = "6.3.0.00.20141121-0732";
}

Comment: What do you mean by the "output". Output of what? How did you generate this JSON string?

Comment: It could very well be that this xcode log happens BEFORE your custom header is added. I believe custom headers are added at the last minute before the request is sent.